# Combining 2 SELECT queries and printing the results in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, php, union

I have 2 queries which I want to use together to produce one output result to the user. The output describes to the user the journey to take to from A to B. I keep getting a syntax error when I try to combine both queries with `UNION`:

> ```
> Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near "UNION" LINE 6: UNION ^
> ```

I have had a look at a similar question but the solutions & discussions provided do not seem to work.

```
$name = pg_escape_string($_POST['name']); // Start destination from user input
$name2 = pg_escape_string($_POST['name2']); // End destination from user input

//If no results are given, the following query below will execute instead.

if (pg_num_rows($result) == 0 ) {

$query = "SELECT dt1.name as name1,dt1.time as time1,dt2.name as name2,dt2.time as time2
From departure_times as dt1
inner join departure_times as dt2 on dt2.tram_id = dt1.tram_id
where dt1.name = '$name' and dt2.name = 'CitySquare' LIMIT 5 

UNION 

SELECT dt1.name as name3,dt1.time as time3,dt2.name as name4,dt2.time as time4
From departure_times as dt1
inner join departure_times as dt2 on dt2.tram_id = dt1.tram_id
where dt1.name = 'CitySquare' and dt2.name = '$name2' LIMIT 5";
$result = pg_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());
} ...
```

The desired output:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
    name1 | time1  | name2  | time2 | name3 |  time3    | name4  | time4
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Change your aliases in the second UNION to dt3 & 4.

Comment: @Vérace: There is no need, `SELECT` statements of a  `UNION` query have separate scopes.

Answer (score 6):

The primary solution is to add parentheses:

```
(  -- parentheses required!
SELECT dt1.name AS name1, dt1.time AS time1
     , dt2.name AS name2, dt2.time AS time2
FROM   departure_times dt1
JOIN   departure_times dt2 USING (tram_id)
WHERE  dt1.name = '$name'
AND    dt2.name = 'CitySquare'
-- no ORDER BY?
LIMIT  5 
)
UNION ALL  -- see below
(
SELECT dt1.name, dt1.time, dt2.name, dt2.time  -- see below
FROM   departure_times dt1
JOIN   departure_times dt2 USING (tram_id)
WHERE  dt1.name = 'CitySquare'
AND    dt2.name = '$name2'
-- no ORDER BY?
LIMIT  5
);
```

Without extra parentheses `LIMIT` is only allowed once at the end of the query and applies to the result of the `UNION`. To attach a `LIMIT` to each `SELECT` parentheses are ***required***.

[The manual:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-UNION)

> The `UNION` clause has this general form:
>
> ```
> select_statement UNION [ ALL | DISTINCT ] select_statement
> ```
>
> ***`select_statement`*** is any `SELECT` statement without an `ORDER BY`, `LIMIT`, `FOR NO KEY UPDATE`, `FOR UPDATE`, `FOR SHARE`, or `FOR KEY SHARE` clause. (`ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` can be attached to a
>   subexpression if it is enclosed in parentheses. Without parentheses,
>   these clauses will be taken to apply to the result of the `UNION`, not
>   to its right-hand input expression.)

Other notes:

- I switched to `UNION ALL` - assuming you don't actually want to try and fold duplicate rows.
- Names of result columns are determined by first `SELECT` of a `UNION` query. Names (or aliases) in all following `SELECT` statements are ignored.
- You may want to add `ORDER BY` to each `SELECT`. `LIMIT` without prior `ORDER BY` returns an arbitrary selection that can change with every execution - in simple queries determined by the physical order of rows in the table (or in the index), which can change any time.