# PostgreSQL - Create table as select with distinct on specific columns

Tags: postgresql

I need a script to create a table . The problem is my select for creating the table contains equal values in some rows. I need to use distinct for these columns. The other columns' values can come from any matching row.

My current result table has data like this:

```
|   CITY   |   STREET   |   STREET_NUM   |   VAL_X   |   VAL_Y   |
------------------------------------------------------------------
| CityA    | Street abc |   5            | 11.5      |   0.5     |
| CityA    | Street abc |   5            | 15.4      |   1.8     |
| CityA    | Street abc |   5            | 12.4      |   2.8     |
| CityB    | Street xyz |   18           |  5.4      |   1.9     |
| CityB    | Street xyz |   18           |  8.4      |   1.1     |
| CityC    | Street klm |   55           |  9.6      |   0.8     |
```

But I need data like this:

```
|   CITY   |   STREET   |   STREET_NUM   |   VAL_X   |   VAL_Y   |
------------------------------------------------------------------
| CityA    | Street abc |   5            | 11.5      |   0.5     |
| CityB    | Street xyz |   18           |  5.4      |   1.9     |
| CityC    | Street klm |   55           |  9.6      |   0.8     |
```

For columns city, street and street_num I need to apply distinct. val_x and val_y should be used anyone, for example first of that group with same city, street and street_num.

Can you give me advice how to edit this script?

Comment: Will there be "duplicates"  than need elimination between the different tables (a row from A and another from B)?

Comment: I got your question wrong, I didn't notice that you were creating table, this is why my answer is irrelevant and I have deleted it. If you add your select query in the place of `my_result` table(refer to the fiddle) then it might work as you expected. And yes, my sample data was different. The values in my example were rounded up. [Here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=298ce1205b3d9e666c02bf06a2b558a1) is the fiddle.

Comment: **1.** This is ambiguous: `city, street and street_num I need to apply distinct`. Is that supposed to be `DISTINCT ON (city, street, street_num)` or `DISTINCT ON (city)` and `DISTINCT ON (street)` and `DISTINCT ON (street_num)` -  in this case you need to define priorities or you get arbitrary results. Very different cases. **2.** Do `val_x` and `val_y` have to come from the *same* (even if arbitrary) row? **3.** We need table definitions showing data types and constraints and your version of Postgres to give the best answer.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter the answer to (2) is yes (was posted in a comment.)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: Ah, I see. Goes to demonstrate the conventional wisdom: all defining information should go into the question ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### "VAL_X" and "VAL_Y" chosen through some aggregate function

You should consider using `GROUP BY` for the columns whose values you consider that should be "distinct" (as a group), and, for the rest of columns, choose an appropriate aggregate function (for instance, `MIN`):

```
CREATE TABLE my_result AS 
SELECT
  city, street, streetnum, min(val_x) AS val_x, min(val_y) AS val_y
FROM
  tableA
WHERE
  true /* your condition goes here */ 
GROUP BY
  city, street, streetnum
```

If you need to put together values from several tables, `UNION ALL` of them before you `GROUP BY`:

```
CREATE TABLE my_result AS 
SELECT
  city, street, streetnum, min(val_x) AS val_x, min(val_y) AS val_y
FROM
  (
  SELECT city, street, streetnum, val_x, val_y FROM tableA
  UNION ALL
  SELECT city, street, streetnum, val_x, val_y FROM tableB
  UNION ALL
  SELECT city, street, streetnum, val_x, val_y FROM tableC
  ) AS s0
WHERE
  true /* your condition goes here */ 
GROUP BY
  city, street, streetnum ;
```

### Using always "VAL_X" and "VAL_Y" from same row, using a WINDOW

If you need to make sure your values are always from the same row, the best way is to use a [`WINDOW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) in your query: `PARTITION BY "CITY", "STREET", "STREET_NUM"` and `ORDER BY "VAL_X", "VAL_Y"`, and choose the first row of every partition.

You can do this with two steps:

1) Add the [`row_num()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE) to every partition:

```
SELECT 
  *,   
  (row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY "CITY", "STREET", "STREET_NUM" ORDER BY "VAL_X", "VAL_Y")) AS rn
FROM 
  table_a

  |  CITY |     STREET | STREET_NUM | VAL_X | VAL_Y | rn |
  |-------|------------|------------|-------|-------|----|
  | CityA | Street abc |          5 |  11.5 |   0.5 |  1 |
  | CityA | Street abc |          5 |  12.4 |   2.8 |  2 |
  | CityA | Street abc |          5 |  15.4 |   1.8 |  3 |
  | CityB | Street xyz |         18 |   5.4 |   1.9 |  1 |
  | CityB | Street xyz |         18 |   8.4 |   1.1 |  2 |
  | CityC | Street klm |         55 |   9.6 |   0.8 |  1 |
```

2) At this point, choose only the rows `WHERE rn=1` (and `ORDER` them, if necessary):

```
SELECT
   "CITY", "STREET", "STREET_NUM", "VAL_X", "VAL_Y"
FROM
  (
  SELECT 
    *,   
    (row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY "CITY", "STREET", "STREET_NUM" ORDER BY "VAL_X", "VAL_Y")) AS rn
  FROM 
    table_a
  ) AS table_a_grouped 
WHERE
  rn = 1
ORDER BY 
  "CITY", "STREET", "STREET_NUM"
```

The result is:

```
|  CITY |     STREET | STREET_NUM | VAL_X | VAL_Y |
|-------|------------|------------|-------|-------|
| CityA | Street abc |          5 |  11.5 |   0.5 |
| CityB | Street xyz |         18 |   5.4 |   1.9 |
| CityC | Street klm |         55 |   9.6 |   0.8 |
```

You can see the example at [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/58286/10/0)

Comment: but this should got me val_x from 1. record and val_y from last recors. I need this couple from anyone row, but must be from same record

Comment: You can use a `FIRST` aggregate function, as explained https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/First/last_(aggregate). You could also use WINDOWs. It would make much more sense if there were a concept of ORDER.

Comment: Added WINDOW example.

Answer (score 3):

Assumptions:

- Resulting rows shall be distinct on `(city, street, street_num)` i.e. the *combination* of these 3 columns shall be unique. Individual columns can have dupes.
- `val_x` and `val_y` (and possibly more columns) shall come from the *same* source row (they make sense *together*, like coordinates / a geocode).
- All columns are defined `NOT NULL`.
  <sub>NULL values are considered *equal* in by `DISTINCT` or `DISTINCT ON` (per SQL standard). So the query works with NULL values all the same. But if you add `ORDER BY` to define which row to pick from each set of dupes, pay attention if expressions can be NULL. See linked answer below for details.</sub>

`UNION ALL` multiple sources, then apply `DISTINCT ON (city, street, street_num)` on the derived table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_result AS 
SELECT DISTINCT ON (city, street, street_num)
       city, street, street_num, val_x, val_y     -- more columns?
FROM (
   SELECT city, street, street_num, val_x, val_y  -- more columns?
   FROM   tableA
   WHERE  ...

   UNION ALL  -- here probably cheaper than UNION
   SELECT city, street, street_num, val_x, val_y  -- more columns?
   FROM   tableB
   WHERE  ...
   ) sub;
```

Results as desired.

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=2883b0768c724f6f2db9e8535274b307)*

It's probably cheaper to use a simple `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` - which would not be wrong but impose a separate sort or hash operation on each `SELECT` of the `UNION` query. Since we do that (and more) in the outer query anyway, `UNION ALL` is probably cheaper. (Test to verify.)

- [Combining 2 SELECT queries and printing the results in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/131231/combining-2-select-queries-and-printing-the-results-in-postgresql/131251#131251)

I did not add `ORDER BY`, since you explicitly stated:

> The other columns' values can come from any matching row.

You get an arbitrary pick from each set of dupes. The result can change with every invocation.

Works in basically *any* Postgres version. There are query techniques with `LATERAL` joins, CTE or window functions that require a more modern version.

Detailed discussion of the technique, indexes and possible alternatives:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860)

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I was thinking. Another possible solution - which I think could be efficient - but should be used only if there are duplicates only in each table and not across tables (as it would yield different results otherwise): `SELECT DISTINCT ON (city, street, street_num) * FROM tableA UNION ALL SELECT DISTINCT ON (city, street, street_num) * FROM tableB ... ;`