# Get rows for a given time range, plus one preceding row

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in which I have queries that return data for a time range. The rows are sparse and events can be days apart.

I am looking for a way to get the data from the range + add the row before the range starts (which can be at any timestamp which is less than the start).

For example:

```
2020-01-01 xxxxxxx
2020-01-12 xxxxxxx
2020-02-10 xxxxxxx
2020-02-11 xxxxxxx
2020-02-15 xxxxxxx
```

If I query from `2020-02-08` to `2020-02-14`, I would get:

```
2020-02-10 xxxxxxx
2020-02-11 xxxxxxx
```

But I would like to get:

```
2020-01-12 xxxxxxx
2020-02-10 xxxxxxx
2020-02-11 xxxxxxx
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: @mustaccio, how does it help for this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fastest and simplest:

```
(  -- parentheses required
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  dt < '2020-02-08'
ORDER  BY dt DESC
LIMIT  1
)

UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  dt BETWEEN '2020-02-08' AND '2020-02-14'
-- ORDER BY dt -- optional
;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LMzR0-tS)

With an **index** on `(dt)` you get two very fast index scans.

If there can be duplicates on `(dt)`, you'll have to define which preceding row to pick, or accept the arbitrary pick from the given query.

Use `UNION ALL`, not `UNION`, which would try to remove duplicates - which is either a waste of time or not what you want. `UNION` can also reorder result rows as a side effect.

About parentheses in `UNION` queries:

- [Combining 2 SELECT queries and printing the results in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/131231/combining-2-select-queries-and-printing-the-results-in-postgresql/131251#131251)

This *normally* returns rows sorted by `dt`. But see:

- [Is order preserved after UNION in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31976967/939860)
- [Are results from UNION ALL clauses always appended in order?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/316818/are-results-from-union-all-clauses-always-appended-in-order)

So you may want to append `ORDER BY dt` as commented to guarantee sorted results.

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution which will give the desired result , but for larger data you might have some performance issue.

To find the previous ,current value of the `2020-02-10` ,

```
with cte as (
SELECT  dt,
        LAG(dt,1) OVER ( ORDER BY dt asc ) AS previous_dt
FROM test_tbl 
  ) select previous_dt as dt from cte where  '2020-02-10' IN (dt,previous_dt);
```

Use union to combine with the range search,

```
with cte as (
SELECT  dt,
        LAG(dt,1) OVER ( ORDER BY dt asc ) AS previous_dt
FROM test_tbl 
  ) select previous_dt as dt from cte where  '2020-02-10' IN (dt,previous_dt)
    union 
    SELECT dt
    FROM test_tbl 
    WHERE dt >='2020-02-08' AND dt<='2020-02-14'  ;
```

> Result,
>
> ```
>    dt
> 2020-01-12
> 2020-02-11
> 2020-02-10
> ```

See example [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/EtZMYDjc)

Comment: This is way more expensive than it needs to be.